# Скажите пожалуйста как можно создать виртуальный CapsLock

Tags: javascript

У меня есть input и checkbox надо чтобы при нажатие на кнопку регистр менялся на верхний а после повторного нажатия снова менялся на нижний регистр Скажите пожалуйста как можно это сделать без jQuery

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А у вас уже есть решение на jQuery?) К тому же, капс не просто делает всё заглавным, а как-бы инвертирует case. И не совсем понятно, нужно инвертировать то, что уже введено, или если нажали кнопку - начать на ходу инвертировать всё, что будут вводить? Второй вариант значительно сложнее.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте так:

```js
document.getElementById("switch").onclick = function(){ 
    var text =document.getElementById("text"); 
    text.value = this.checked ? text.value.toUpperCase() : text.value.toLowerCase();
};
```

```html
<input type="text" value="text_default" id="text" />
<span>Caps</span><input type="checkbox" id="switch" />
```